# wake computer up when IP is pinged

Tags: windows-7, networking, sleep, c++, c

i want to wake my computer using WoL or a "VTL"(Virtual Tripline). but, because i am on a router with other devices, i cannot use WoL. Then I looked for a Virtual Tripline on google - no results that i want. So my friend, who suggested to get a VTL, said if I could make a C/C++ scrip that would wake the computer when its IP is pinged, with a port on it (rm-servers.no-ip.org:25570),it will wake the computer out of sleep mode. But idk how to do this and i need some help because i dont know alot of C/C++. can someone tell me how to put it on the computer that is in sleep mode? or, which i don't prefer, on another computer?

Technical Specs:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix:
Description: Marvell Yukon 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Physical Address: ‎00-13-D4-9C-2D-60
DHCP Enabled: Yes
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.105
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
IPv4 WINS Server:
NetBIOS over Tcpip Enabled: Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80::4b6:9454:25e0:171e%12
IPv6 Default Gateway:
IPv6 DNS Server:

Comment: Have you considered an inexpensive Raspberry Pi as a WoL server? http://www.jeremyblum.com/2013/07/14/rpi-wol-server/

Answer (score 2):

I'd be very surprised if this is possible as "WoL" is additional functionality baked into the hardware of the network card where it is available.

For what you are trying to do, your computers network stack would need to be in a useable state, which implies the system is not sleeping, thus it is unavailable to you.

I'm not sure what you mean by you are "on a router with other devices".  If you are on the same subnet/lan as the device you want to wake up you can use WoL as it does not go through the router.  If you do need to go through the router then that is substantially harder though.

Comment: i need to go thru the router.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are trying to do is wake a machine within a network, where you are on an external network?

If so then your friend seems to be on the right track here. You have a bit of research to do.

The only option that I know of, is to have another machine (preferably something low power like a NAS/raspberry pi) that listens to incoming packets on a specific port attached to the same subnet as your target machine (you will need to forward that port on the router). If the machine receives a "wake up $ip" message of some sort, it will send a WOL request in the subnet to the ip address that you passed it (or hard-coded).

I'm not familiar with running linux-based routers, but that would be your second option.

I'm not able to look right now, but when I get home, I will update with any packages I can find that can do this.